# Import a tff font to css in vue

Tags: css, vue.js

Im started a new vue project and havnt installed any npm packages. Not sure if ill need to for this to work but im trying to import a font and use it as a font family.

The font is in `src/assets/fonts/josefin/thin.tff`

In my css i use

```
//Fonts
@font-face {
  font-family: "Josefin-thin";
  src: url("/assets/fonts/josefin/thin.tff");
}
```

and im using it by doing `font-family: 'Josefin-thin';`

Im not getting any errors but the font isnt applying. Do I need to install webpack? thanks

Comment: did you use vue-cli ?

Comment: @Daniel I found these 3 in the package.json so i think so - @vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",

Comment: probably so, if that's the case, webpack is already installed and that should work. Maybe try without the leading `/` in the url.